# Show/Hide fields on One2many tree - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have some fields I'm showing in my `One2many` tree view:

```
  <page string="Budget Lines Planned">
            <field name="account_budget_bsi_line" colspan="4" nolabel="1" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','!=','draft')]}">
                <tree string="Budget Lines Planned" editable="bottom" >
                    <field name="opening_stock"/>
                    <field name="sales_planned" />
                    <field name="amount_total"/>
                    <field name="interauxiliary_transfers_planned" />
                    <field name="interauxiliary_receipts_planned" />
                    <field name="prod_purchased_planned" />
                    <field name="closing_stock_planned" />
                </tree>
            </field>
    </page>
```

This is from a custom module, which has a workflow with states, ie: `draft, approved, next, done` etc.

Suppose on `next` state, I want to hide `opening_stock` field, and show some other field.

I know this can be achieved on forms by using `attrs="{'readonly':[('state','!=','draft')]}"` or invisible or whatever.

But doesn't seem to work on `One2many` tree views, so, how can I achieve that in this case?

Comment: Put them in invisible instead of readonly, it will not show them, it will be like an empty column. Try it and tell me

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't work like that, sorry, I tried before, this is a one2many tree, not a "conventional" one

Comment: I've seen this invisible="context.get('state')=='next'" , doesn't give me any errors, but still not hiding it, the problem is the one2many field, we'll wait for some hint about this scenario

Comment: but you cant modify if you put it as invisible

Comment: Thanks, but that is beyond the scope of the question, the reasons are many for me to want to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there is no way to dynamically hide an entire column of a `One2many` field's tree. You can dynamically hide the column's contents per row with `attrs`. In the case below, if the line had a Name of "Example", then it would show as a blank cell when in a Draft state.

```
<field name="opening_stock" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'draft')]}"/>
```

If you really must show a different `One2many` tree view, then you can try using multiple field/tree definitions in the view and using the `attrs` on the `One2many` field itself like so:

```
<field name="account_budget_bsi_line" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '=', 'draft')]}">
    <tree>
        ...
        <field name="opening_stock"/>
        ...
    </tree>
</field>
<field name="account_budget_bsi_line" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'draft')]}">
    <tree>
        ...
        <!-- Exclude field opening_stock -->
        ...
    </tree>
</field>
```

I'm not sure if this will work for your needs, but it's the closest I can think to a solution.

Comment: Something like this it's exactly what I'm doing, and Yes, AFAIK there is no way to dinamically hide them so I'm using something very similar to this for my project, hiding based on states, and that's it. Thank You very much anyways.